# Configuration for CRUD&List operations for $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Something like this, but working for CRUD&List. Here is what I did but the 'list overrides edit'...

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('admin.quicklinks', {
      url: '/quicklinks',
      templateUrl: ...
    })
    .state('admin.quicklinks.list', {
      url: '/list',
      templateUrl: ...
    })
    .state('admin.quicklinks.add', {
      url: '/add',
      templateUrl: ...
    })
    .state('admin.quicklinks.edit', {
      url: '/:id',
      templateUrl: ...
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, sorry guys. In original source code the latest state definition for `admin.quicklinks.edit` contains additionally a definition for `resolve` which was wrong and caused the route not to change. That was the reason for the "strange" behavior, which was actually completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a quicklink with an `id` if `"list"` this would be incompatible with your states.  Instead you could just use:

```
.state('admin.quicklinks.edit', {
    url: '/edit/:id'
```